# Bulk Insert SetDouble OCCI

Tags: c++, occi

I am working on an application where I have C++ float and double variables to be inserted into Oracle tables with columns declared as number with precision and scale using OCCI function setDouble. My question is how do I convert the c++ double variable to fit into the precision and scale specified in the metadata of that table. For Example, this is my table definition.

```
CREATE
TABLE test
(
    SId                  NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    SCtgy               CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    ClusterId            VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    NetValue              NUMBER(22,4) NOT NULL
);
```

NetValue is declared as c++ double, now before inserting it database I want to convert this value into the exact precision and scale (22,4) in this example. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You need to provide lot more context for this question to make any sense. Currently the answer is: You dont convert anything, because `double`s are numbers

Comment: I don't recommend `setDouble` or `setNumber`, as you have not presented any information about them.  Use `std::ostream` and look at the `fill`, `width` and `setprecision` I/O manipulators.